# List<String> find and replace values by part of string

Tags: c#, .net, list, data-structures

I have a `List<String>` which contains values like `Char:Char_Number1_Number2`.
I want to **find the index** or **replace the value**, by searching `Number1_Number2`, the combination of `Number1_Number2` is always unique.

EG: **B:S_4_0**  will be replaced as **B:S_5_1** , But searching criteria is  **4_0**

```
B:S_4_0
B:N_1_2
A:N_3_3
B:N_0_0
A:S_2_5
A:S_3_4
```

I want these tasks

1. How to **find the index** or complete value by using the second half of the string
2. How to replace or **remove** a specific value by using the second half of the string

---

```
int index = Player1.IndexOf("5_6");    // Find Index
Player1[index]="5_6";                  // Replace value
Player1.Remove("5_6");                 // Remove
```

---

References

[How to replace some particular string in a list of type string using linq](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8063058/how-to-replace-some-particular-string-in-a-list-of-type-string-using-linq)

[How to replace list item in best way](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17188966/how-to-replace-list-item-in-best-way)

[C#: Update Item value in List](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32993562/c-update-item-value-in-listof-t)

Comment: **B:S_4_0**  will be replaced as **B:S_5_1** ,, But searching Criteria is  **4_0**

Comment: `num_num` can't be converted to an int. Are you looking to make this into string key?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will replace `B:S_4_0` by `B:S_5_1`, serching for `4_0`

```
List<string> lstString = new List<string> {"B:S_4_0", "B:N_1_2", "A:N_3_3", "B:N_0_0", "A:S_2_5", "A:S_3_4"};

int j = lstString.FindIndex(i => i.Contains("4_0")); //Finds the item index

lstString[j] = lstString[j].Replace("4_0", "5_1"); //Replaces the item by new value
```

Answer (score 2):

```
int index = list.FindIndex(i => i.Contains("4_0"));

list[index] = list[index].Replace("4_0", "5_6");
```

Hope this will help :)

Answer (score 1):

Find index (returns `-1` if not found):

```
int index = list.FindIndex(s => s.EndsWith("4_0"));
```

Replace:

```
list[index] = list[index].Replace("4_0", "5_1");
```

Remove:

```
list.RemoveAt(index);
```